# How to escape ' inside " in perl?

Tags: perl, escape-characters

I'm using the following script, but getting unexpected output.

```
perl -pi -e '/DB_CHARSET/ and $_.="define('SOMETHING'/, true);\n"' file.txt
```

This command adds `define(SOMETHING, true);`

Since the text starts with ' then have " inside, how do I escape 'SOMETHING so that I end up with `define('SOMETHING', true)`?

I've tried usual \ and it did not help.

Comment: See also [How to use a special character as a normal one?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Comment: Of course this is a shell escape problem, not a Perl problem.  A silly solution to smuggling in a single quote is to switch quotation styles to `"'"` for the single quote, then switch back:  `$ perl -E 'say '"'"'As far as the Perl interpreter knows, this string is single quoted'"'"`

Comment: @LSpice, it's the use of a single-quoted string in the shell command line that makes passing the `'` an issue, but it can be solved in the shell _or_ in Perl.

Comment: It's important to mention that you want the single quote as a string, not interpreted as perl.  Because if the function in question was going to be perl, we could use the quote-like operators `q` or `qq` : `perl -pi -e '/DB_CHARSET/ and $_.=qq{define(q{SOMETHING}/, true);\n}' file.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use e.g. `\x27` in the Perl string (the character code for `'` in hex):

```
$ perl -e 'print "foo\x27bar"' -l
foo'bar
```

or handle the quoting in the shell so as to give Perl a raw `'`:

```
$ perl -e 'print "foo'\''bar"' -l
foo'bar
```

(First `'` ends the quoted string, `\'` inserts the quote, the third `'` starts a new quoted string.)

Comment: In addition to `'\''` some shells have a setting that allow the use of `''` to put an apostrophe into a single quoted string. (In zsh this behavior can be enabled with the command `setopt RC_QUOTES`, and disabled again with `setopt NO_RC_QUOTES`.) Maybe something similar exists for your shell?) with such a setting enabled one could write the above command as: `perl -e 'print "foo''bar"' -l`

Answer (score 6):

You can change every `'` to `'\''`. But that will get ugly soon.

A better idea is to use a here-document for your script:

```
perl -pi - <<'EOT' file.txt
/DB_CHARSET/ and $_.="define('SOMETHING'/, true);\n"
EOT
```

Notice the quotes around `EOT`. If the here-document terminator is not in (single or double) quotes, `$`-starting variables, arithmetic substitutions, backticks, etc will be expanded within the here-document. This is a bit different from here-documents in perl, where only single quotes will prevent variable expansions.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the `-s` to turn on rudimentary switch processing on the perl commandline and thence define a single quote there:

```
$ perl -spi -e '$_  .= qq/define(${q}SOMETHING$q, true);/' -- -q=\'   file
```